# Sniffing detection

Tags: networking, network-programming, mac-address, icmp

Can someone tell me how exactly works "test ICMP"? (One of methods to detect sniffing in local network)

Comment: Your phrasing doesn't make any sense to me.  Maybe you can clarify?

Comment: I heard about sending packet ICMP to host that is suspected to be sniffer. This packet should have some changes (MAC address of sth) but I'm not sure what and why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sniffing detection is basically detecting if there are any sniffers in your network. The main feature of sniffers that is used to detect them is that they place the network card in promiscuous mode, listening for all traffic. Typically, a sniffer is placed on a machine with a full TCP/IP stack which will be affected by this mode.

ICMP is the protocol behind the `ping` command. To ping a machine, you send an ICMP Echo request packet to it and wait for an ICMP response one. Usually, the ICMP request is embedded in an Ethernet packet to be delivered across the network. A standard Ethernet packet would include the MAC address of the addressed network card, as well as the IP address of that machine in the embedded ICMP packet. The packet would be detected by the appropriate card and that machine would respond to the `ping`. This is the standard process.

Now let's see what happens if we sent a `ping` packet (ICMP Echo request one) with the IP address of the suspected sniffer address but with a *different*, faulty MAC address in the Ethernet envelope.

1. If the network card in the sniffer machine is *not* on promiscuous mode, then the packet will *not* be received by that machine. Naturally, the machine wouldn't respond. The `ping` attempt would fail.
2. If the network card in the sniffer machine is on promiscuous mode, then the machine will see *all* packets in the network. The TCP/IP stack on that machine would thus accept the `ping` packet by identifying the received packet IP address. The stack would thus send a response. The `ping` attempt would *succeed*.

Similar to other methods of detection, this has false positives as well as false negatives. The sniffer machine may be instructed to ignore all ICMP requests. Detecting promiscuous mode is not exactly detecting sniffers, though it is a very significant clue.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I need :) Do you know maybe how to send some icmp packet like this (to suspected ip but different, faulty mac address) in .NET/C#?